# rails 3 validate uniqueness through foreign reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A can have many B's

B can have many C's

C's name must be unique within a B

C's name must be unique within an A

in Rails3 i can obtain the first constraint by writing the following

validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => :A_id}

however C is not directly linked to A how do i assure that no 2 C's can have the same name, given an A.

i tried something like this
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => self.B.A_id}
but this does not seem to work

Comment: B's name is unique given an A yes

Comment: I think you need to write custom validation function that tests for existence of C`s name inside of A.cs.

Comment: Yeah i asked one of the assistance of my school, he suggested the same thing.. thanks for the help though.